# Symfony MediaBundle sonata_media_type не показывает превью картинки в formfields sonata admin

Tags: symfony3, sonata

Сделал связь и админку по документации https://sonata-project.org/blog/2013/10/11/mediabundle-mediatype-improved .
в формбилдере для поля картинки указываю sonata_media_type с передачей нужных параметров, контекст и провайдер.  В ListFields картинку показывает(подключил сонатовский шаблон для листа). В Формбилдере даже не рендерит медиа виджет, просто fileloader( кнопка загрузить) , если дампить данные(dump(this-,>getSubject()->getLogo()) данные приходят( медиа обьект). Что можно сделать что б в редактировании заработал стандартный шаблон для поля sonata_media_type ? p.s ошибок никаких нету (symfony 3.4)

Comment: По идее filesystem должен быть настроен еще. 
 `filesystem:
        local:
            directory:  "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/media"
            create:     true`

Comment: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.html